# Java applet dispose window after closing applet

Tags: java, applet, acm-java-libraries

Just a quick question. I am creating an applet in Eclipse with Java.
I run the program, the applet appears on the screen and everything is good.
But when I hit close (cross on the applet window) it closes the window, and the clean grey window stays on the screen with words "**applet disposed**". Sometimes after half a minute it closes by itself.

[image]

How can I get rid of this window? I am on osx.

```
/* 
* File: Add3Inegers.java
* ---------------------------
* This program adds 3 integers.
*/

/* Library Package imports */

import acm.program.*;

//import java.awt.*;

/* Creates Add3Integers class */

public class Add3Integers extends ConsoleProgram {

    /* Set Applet window dimensions */
    public void init() {
        setSize(500, 500);
    }
    /* Creates run() method */
    public void run() {
        println("This program adds three integers.");
        int n1 = readInt("Enter first number:");
        int n2 = readInt("Enter second number:");
        int n3 = readInt("Enter third number:");
        int total = n1 + n2 + n3;
        println("The total is: " + total + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a sample code to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi, I dont think it is a problem with code.

Comment: I've just started to learn Java by Stanford CS106a. And I am using their start project with acm libraries. Here is a cod:

Comment: I tried on Windows 7 and my program closes immediately when I click the X you mentioned after copy/pasting your code.  I am running Java 7.

Comment: Cool installed JDK 7 and all works fine now. Thanks

Comment: See also this related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17872245/230513).