# Cannot create multiple polygons in Java - only one

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

Given the following code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/**
 * 
 * @author X2
 *
 */
public class PolygonnerJframe
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw polygons");
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setContentPane(new DrawingPanel());
     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}




/**
 * Main class
 * @author X2
 *
 */
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Dimension MIN_DIM = new Dimension(300, 300);
    private static final Dimension PREF_DIM = new Dimension(500, 500);
    private boolean polygonDone = false;
    private final Point trackPoint = new Point(); // The 'dummy' point tracking the mouse
    private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(); // The list of points making up a polygon
    private ArrayList<Point> helper = new ArrayList<Point>(); // The list of points making up a polygon


    public ArrayList<Point> copyCreate(ArrayList<Point> input , ArrayList<Point> output)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (output == null)
            output = new ArrayList<Point>();
        while (i < input.size())
        {
            output.add(input.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        return output;
    }




    /**
     * Setting the dimensions of the windows
     */
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() { return MIN_DIM; }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() { return PREF_DIM; }



    /**
     *  The only constructor needed for this class
     */
    DrawingPanel()
    {
        super();
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }



    /**
     *  The drawing itself 
     */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int numPoints = points.size();
        if (numPoints == 0)
            return; // nothing to draw


        Point prevPoint = (Point) points.get(0);

        // draw polygon
        Iterator<Point> it = points.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Point curPoint = (Point) it.next();
            draw(g, prevPoint, curPoint);           
            prevPoint = curPoint;
        }

        // now draw tracking line or complete the polygon
        if (polygonDone == true)
        {
            draw(g, prevPoint, (Point) points.get(0));
        }

        else  // polygonDone == false
            draw(g, prevPoint, trackPoint); 

    }





    /**
     * MouseListener interface 
     */
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
    {
        int x = evt.getX();
        int y = evt.getY();

        switch (evt.getClickCount())
        {
            case 1: // single-click
                if (polygonDone == true)
                {
                    this.helper = this.copyCreate(this.points, this.helper);  // copy the new coordinates into the helper 
                    points.clear();
                    polygonDone = false;
                }
                points.add(new Point(x, y));
                repaint();
                break;

            case 2: // double-click
                polygonDone = true;
                points.add(new Point(x, y));
                // repaint();
                break;

            default: // ignore anything else
                break;
        }
    }






    /**
     * MouseMotionListener interface 
     */
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt)
    {
        trackPoint.x = evt.getX();
        trackPoint.y = evt.getY();
        repaint();
    }



    /**
     * draw points and lines 
     * @param g
     * @param p1
     * @param p2
     */
    private void draw(Graphics g, Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        int x1 = p1.x;
        int y1 = p1.y;

        int x2 = p2.x;
        int y2 = p2.y;

        // draw the line first so that the points
        // appear on top of the line ends, not below
        g.setColor(Color.green.darker());
        g.drawLine(x1 + 3, y1 + 3, x2 + 3, y2 + 3);
        g.drawLine(x1 + 4, y1 + 4, x2 + 4, y2 + 4);
        g.drawLine(x1 + 5, y1 + 5, x2 + 5, y2 + 5);

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(x1, y1, 8, 8);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(x2, y2, 8, 8);
    }





    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) { /* EMPTY */ }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) { /* EMPTY */ }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) { /* EMPTY */ }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) { /* EMPTY */ }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) { /* EMPTY */ }
}
```

I can only draw one polygon each time , meaning - when I try to start a new polygon 
the "old" polygon vanishes , but I don't understand why .

So how can I draw multiple polygons ?

What causes the old polygon to vanish ? I thought maybe due to `repaint()` , but I tried without it but it didn't help .

I'd appreciate your help

Comment: Could it be that it has to do something with the line `points.clear();` ? Haven't used the canvas for a long time, but I think the draw method is actually called for every frame update for your display, meaning, when the points are no longer available in your list they can't get painted. So, you may have to create a new List with points each time you want a new polygon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polygons are indeed being erased by calling `points.clear()`. To counter this, you could to maintain co-ordinate information using the [Polygon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) class about previous polygons in a separate `List` which could be painted along with the "in-progress" polygon. This is outlined in [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

Comment: +1, Java already supports a Polygon class to which you add the point to make up your Polygon. So your List should contain Polygons, not individual points. Then you can paint the Polygons using the Graphics2D.draw(Shape), or fill(Shape) method.

Comment: @Reimeus: Okay thank you ,what about removing `points.clear();` and deal with the consequences ? I've tried to remove it and it has indeed caused some problems...+1

Comment: You will still need to call `points.clear()` but you will need to create a new `Polygon` and add to your new `List<PolyGon>`, then draw these in `paintComponent` before drawing the _active_ shape. See this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854678/animation-handling-several-cycle?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: @Reimeus: I'm working on it now , I'll get back to U. Thanks a lot !