# Trying to draw multiple polygons results in error

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

Following my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649228/cannot-create-multiple-polygons-in-java-only-one/15649335#15649335) , I changed the code to  :

**PolygonnerJframe.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/**
 * 
 * @author X2
 *
 */
public class PolygonnerJframe
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw polygons");
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setContentPane(new DrawingPanel());
     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Now , this code results in : [image: this]

And I can't understand what causes this .

The changes that I've made are : when we're done with a polygon , its coordinates are saved in the arrayList of class `Polygon` , and each time that I create a new polygon , I take 
the previous polygons and draw them , while drawing a new polygon .

As you can see above , something went wrong with the drawing and I can't seem to find 
the problem .

I'd appreciate any help .

Thanks

**EDIT:**

After taking into consideration what @StanislavL said , I moved those lines to `mouseClicked()` , but this time I get a new screen each time that a new polygon is created without the "old" polygons .

Just a new polygon ... without the old ones

[image]

Comment: You didn't post the most important part - drawing code. BTW: Why can't you use standard Polygon class? You can get source from here http://java-sl.com/shapes.html where regular Polygons are drawn.

Comment: @StanislavL: Of course I did , in the first file (`PolygonnerJframe.java`

)  , under the function `private void draw(Graphics g, Point p1, Point p2)` . This is HW , hence I can't use the Polygon class :)

Answer (score 2):

On each `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` call
you create a new polygon add add it to the polygons list.

```
        Polygon poly = new Polygon(this.edges);

        // add the polygon to the polygons array 
        this.polygons.add(poly);
```

Guess that should happen just one e.g. in the `mouseClicked()` processing

Comment: @StanislavL: It still doesn't work : I moved those lines into `mouseClicked()` overridden method , but this time the screen doesn't show anything except for the NEW polygon . Please see the edited post .

Comment: simple to disable, super.paintComponent(g);, (but be sure that not proper of ways), did you read comment by  @trashgod

Answer (score 2):

@Stas code works for me witout any add_ons (added basic stuff cried in IDE), did you meaning final result could be ???

[image]

.

EDIT

.

dirty hack is disable super.paintComponent(g);, but proper way should be only

- to add all Objects to the array (see quite clear comment by @ trashgod)
- create an BurreferImage as Backgroung Image (after Mouse Double_Click)

output by disable super.paintComponent(g);

[image]

Comment: No, I need to create multiple polygons , where the final Point is attached to the first Point.

Comment: is there some logics, how much points are valid for one Polygon,

Comment: Take for example a triangle , it has 3 points and 3 edges .So I take each edge (where it has 2 points , one for each end) and draw it with `drawline` . That the way I'm trying to work with ,but as you can see ,I got something else .

Comment: +1 In `GraphPanel` each node could be a `Polygon` or `List<Node>` could be the vertices of an editable `Polygon`.

Comment: @trashgod: This is very nice ,but it still does not explain where did I go wrong with my code .

Comment: @ron: Not sure; you might look at [`LinePanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) as an example of animating just the _last_ segment added.

Comment: @trashgod: The thing is , that the locations where the mouse "was" are also counted , not just the locations where I hit "one click" with the mouse ... that's what I'm trying to solve .