# Dragged mouse coordinates are also counted while using mouseClicked()?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, mouseevent

Something very weird is happening when I use the method :

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
```

I count the number of clicks , and each time that I have one click or two clicks , 
I grab the (x,y) coordinate and add that coordinate to my list . 
But when I check the given picture , I see that the added coordinates are also dragged coordinates , i.e. , locations where the user has passed with the mouse , but didn't 
hit a click or double click .

How can that be ?

This questions is associated with my previous questions regarding polygons , and this problem seems to be the cause of my problems .

Here are the pictures : Closing a polygon

: [image]

and when I start to draw something else :

[image]

Meaning is , that's the same polygon , only this time the coordinates where the mouse traveled but DIDN'T hit a click / double click , were also counted .

And [that's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657010/trying-to-draw-multiple-polygons-results-in-error?lq=1) my previous question .

Any idea would to the source of the problem would be greatly appreciated .

The code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/**
 * 
 * @author X2
 *
 */
public class Poly
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw polygons");
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setContentPane(new DrawingPanel());
     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *"Classes `Edges` and `Polygon` are in the given link (if you need them , they are small classes) ."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Sorry ,fixed.

Comment: Hmm.. What is with the plethora of blank lines in the source?  I went through the 454 (!) lines and removed the redundant white space to produce 379 LOC.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: That's the least of my problems :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not completely sure of what the exact problem is, but you should not modify your "model" (Polygon/Edge instances) during `paintComponent`.

When `polygonDone` is `true` (btw, you can simply write `if(polygonDone)`), you are adding new `Edges` to your model. This sounds bad, as you don't control when `paintComponent` is called, nor how many times it is called. And since in `mouseMoved` you call `repaint()`, this will eventually trigger the call to `paintComponent`, create new Edges, etc... The problem must lie somewhere in that code. Stop creating Edges in `paintComponent`.

As a general rule, you should never modify your component state during `paintComponent`, only upon user input (MouseEvent, KeyBoard events (through KeyBindings)).

Comment: I did as you suggested and removed `this.edges.add(currentEdge);` in `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` , but I got the same thing .

Comment: Finally I got it fixed ,using your remarks . Thanks a lot . That `paintComponent` was the main reason for this mess .